# How do I map a local subdomain with WAMP and dnsmasq

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, localhost, wamp, dnsmasq

I have DnsMasq setup on a local Raspberry Pi box to map local devices to simple paths on the network e.g. laptop.local
I use WAMP on my laptop for local web development and this setup is working extremely well, however just to tidy up URL's and for educational purposes, how could I map a subdirectory on my laptop, currently "laptop.local/website" to a subdomain instead e.g. "website.laptop.local"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your DNS is set up correctly for *laptop.local*, you will likely only need to update your WAMP configuration to make use of the appropriate Apache virtual host(s).

**Configuring WAMP**

1. Create a directory to house your sub-domain(s). Make sure this is done in a location which your WAMP installation can access (e.g. under or alongside your root `www` folder).
2. Open Apache *httpd.conf* (located in your WAMP installation under the Apache `conf` directory or through the appropriate menu interface e.g. `Apache → httpd.conf` ).
3. Uncomment this line (remove the #):

   ```
    # Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
   ```

   which should then become

   ```
    Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
   ```
4. Open your Apache `conf\extra` folder and find `httpd-vhosts.conf`. Add something similar to the following at the end of the file:

   ```
   # Virtual host entry for website.laptop.local
   # Anything with a # is a comment

   <VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName website.laptop.local
   #ServerAlias *.website.laptop.local

   # DocumentRoot should correspond to wherever the HTML files
   # for your website.laptop.local site are located. This is an example!

   DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/subdomains/my-website"

   ErrorLog "logs/my-website-error.log"
   CustomLog "logs/my-website-access.log" common

   # If you have any problems with "Forbidden", try uncommenting
   # the following (assumes Apache 2.4.x).

   #<Directory "C:/wamp/www/subdomains/my-website">

        #AllowOverride None
        #Options None
        #Require all granted

   #</Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. Make sure to enable your *alias_module* and *vhost_alias_module* Apache modules.  Usually this is done (again) through the appropriate menu interface e.g. `Apache → Apache modules` but can also potentially be done under `httpd.conf` by simply uncommenting the appropriate module lines.
6. Restart your WAMP server.

Assuming there are no errors, *website.laptop.local* should now be available.